# How to use IDENT_Current function on multiple identity columns table

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, sql-server-2014

I want to get the latest inserted record from target table and update the field in source table.

Source:

```
Name company targetID
Jane  YYYY   Null
```

Basically, I am looping the files in SSIS and inserting the target tables via webservice(script task). Each record is created per file . I want to capture the latest ID created in target and update the source field.

Target:

```
ID name   company
1  Jane    YYYY
```

after the row is created in target for a file, I want my source to be
Source:

```
Name company targetID
Jane  YYYY   1
```

If the row is not created ,then do not update source.

I checked for scope_identity(),ident_current but not sure how to use them in my situation as I am inserting target tables via webservice.

Also, my target table can have more than 1 identity column. How do I use Ident_Column on this table?

Any help is appreciated.